# Get Error Message on Office 365 Rest API with CURL

Tags: api, rest, curl, outlook, office365

Im trying to get the error message of the office 365 api with CURL but the body response is always null and the curl_error comes null too.

When I enable the header(commented in the code), the response comes with the header only with no body.

Here's an example code for the photo api where I write the wrong token to invoke the error

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/photo");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer jdbvdbvdjkdvjdsvsd", 
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'Response : <br/>'.$response;
echo 'HTTP Code : '.curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo '<br/>Curl error:<br/> ' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`curl_error($ch)` returns the last error that occurred during a curl session. And this error is not HTTP error, rather it is the error that curl faced.

If you just comment out the two SSL options from your example code, then you'll see below error message from `curl_error($ch)` that your curl faced.

```
Curl error:<br/> SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

If you really need that `status line` message then you have to parse it from the response header. You can use `regex` or `explode` function of php.

Comment: I haven't gotten the error that you've mentioned even after commenting out the two lines. But an invalid token error exists in the header. I guess i'll have to get it via regex. I wish the API would return the error as the response instead of null...